# Changing text "Create new account" in /user tab

Tags: 7, users

Does anybody know how to change the tab text "Create new account" in /user - I am using Drupal 7.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

By writing a custom module that implements hook_menu_alter and alter the title of the menu.
Something like below.

```
mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/register']['title'] = 'New Text';
}
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7